# Could not invoke RNFirebaseFirestore.documentSet

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Hi guys I add this error and I don't understand why... I'm using the starter project of react-native-firebase, and I'm trying to use firestore

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be an issue with the library which needs investigating, your code is generally wrong. State in a React component should be data which when changed, causes a re-render. You do not need to assign your collection to state, this can be done as a class property. Also, using a constructor & componentWillMount is wrong as they're essentially the same thing - I don't know enough how it'd handle both cases internally though.

Your code would better work like so:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.ref.add({ name: 'moo' });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error. Please create the collection with the name 'users' and add a dummy document. Then try.